# Order of slots called on QObject

Tags: qt

I have a QObject that has multiple slots connected to one of its signals. Is there an order in which of each of these slots are called when the signal is emitted?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In Qt v4.5 and earlier: No, the order is undefined as can be seen in [the documentation here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/signalsandslots.html#signals):

> If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be executed one after the other, in an arbitrary order, when the signal is emitted.

Edit: From version 4.6 onwards this is no longer true. Now the slots will run in the order they are connected. The relevant paragraph of [the current documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals):

> If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected, when the signal is emitted

Comment: @Hossein My answer was correct until QT version 4.6. If you look at the date of the question (and my answer), you'll see that it was the correct answer when the question was asked. Note that Yaroslav's answer was posted more than a year later.

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't mean to undervalue your post. Since this question appeared as the first result of the Google search I did, I wanted to stop further readers from confusing.

Comment: you need to use Queued Connections in order to this to be true for different threads. Just saying.

Answer (score 12):

According to Qt documentation:

> If several slots are connected to one
>   signal, the slots will be executed one
>   after the other, in the order they
>   have been connected, when the signal
>   is emitted.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 2):

While the order is undefined, up to now, in all Qt versions it has been `connect()` order, except when `Qt::QueuedConnection` is used, in which case, of course, it's not even guaranteed that any or all slots have been executed when `emit` returns. Relying on the order is still discouraged, though.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on what order the slots will be executed is a bad, bad idea, as it defeats both the spirit of the signals/slots connections and leaves you wide open for undesired behavior if you do any sort of programmatic connections of signals & slots.